# Powershell передача переменной между функциями не вызывая их внутри друг друга

Tags: powershell

Приветствую!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно не записывая вывод функции в файл, передать его на выполнение другой принимающей функции не вызывая предыдущую?

Пример:

```
function name1 {1+1}
function name2 {2+то что получила функция name1}
```

при этом нельзя вызвать функцию name1 внутри функции name2 !
Возможно как нибудь задействовать буфер обмена для временного хранения вывода функции name1 после ее выполнения? Или есть другие способы?

Comment: А переменная, конвеер или параметр не вариант?

Comment: переменная - параметр

Comment: Есть ли возможность из функции как то задавать глобальную переменную?

Comment: *Есть ли возможность из функции как то задавать глобальную переменную?*: `function name1 {${global:то что получила функция name1}=1+1} function name2 {2+${global:то что получила функция name1}} name1; name2`. Только я предпочитаю без необходимости с глобальными переменными не работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что использую переменную посредник

```
function name1 {1+1}
$varname1 = name1;
function name2 {2+$varname1}
name2;
```

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: Дополнение, как частный случай временного решения. Возможно есть другие способы.

Comment: У вас всего 2 варианта: или вызывать первую функцию во второй, или использовать переменную. Если не хотите вызывать, переменная - ваш единственный выход, а не "частный случай временного решения".

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласен.